Why is the damping coefficient in PyTorch not complementary to the momentum coefficient like in traditional SGD?
In traditional stochastic gradient descent (SGD) with momentum, the update rule for the momentum term $m_t$ is typically written as:
$$
m_t = \beta m_{t-1} + (1 - \beta) g_t
$$
where:

$m_t$ is the momentum term,
$g_t$ is the current gradient,
$\beta$ is the momentum coefficient, and
$1 - \beta$ is called the damping coefficient.

In this formulation, the momentum coefficient $\beta$ and the damping coefficient $1 - \beta$ sum to 1.
However, in the official PyTorch documentation, the damping coefficient is defined differently, as $1 - \eta$, This leads to a situation where the momentum coefficient and the damping coefficient do not sum to 1. The update rule in PyTorch for the momentum is given as:
$$
m_t = \beta m_{t-1} + (1-\eta)g_t
$$
Could someone clarify why PyTorch defines the damping coefficient this way? Why doesn't PyTorch follow the classical definition where the momentum and damping coefficients sum to 1?
